# Enzyme Shallow snapshot doesn't care about the order of child components

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, snapshot

I noticed that the snapshot looks like this:

```
exports[`shallow 1`] = `
<div>
  <Component />
  <Component />
</div>
`;
```

Where means when doing snapshot the two components below are identical:

```
export const Page1 = () => {
    return <div>
        <Title/>  
        <Content/>    
    </div>
}

export const Page2 = () => {
    return <div>
        <Content/>  
        <Title/>    
    </div>
}
```

Where Title and Content are:

```
export const Title = ()=>{
    return <h1>Hello World</h1>
}

export const Content= () =>{
    return <p>The quick fox jumped over the brown dog</p>
}
```

I understand that Shallow is not meant to fully render the child components, ie the h1 tags and 'Hello World', but I thought it should at least care the order of those child components?

How do I check that a components children hasn't changed place, or been replaced by other components, without mounting the entire component tree?

**EDIT: Here's the whole of my example.test.js file and the entire snapshot:**

```
import React from "react";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import toJson from 'enzyme-to-json';

export const Page1 = () => {
    return <div>
        <Title/>  
        <Content/>    
    </div>
}

export const Page2 = () => {
    return <div>
        <Content/>  
        <Title/>    
    </div>
}

export const Title = ()=>{
    return <h1>Hello World</h1>
}

export const Content= () =>{
    return <p>The quick fox jumped over the brown dog</p>
}

test("Page", () => {
    const wrapper1 = shallow(<Page1/>);
    const wrapper2 = shallow(<Page2/>);
    expect(toJson(wrapper1)).toMatchSnapshot();
    expect(toJson(wrapper2)).toMatchSnapshot();
})
```

This is the snap it produces

```
// Jest Snapshot v1

exports[`Page 1`] = `
<div>
  <Component />
  <Component />
</div>
`;

exports[`Page 2`] = `
<div>
  <Component />
  <Component />
</div>
`;
```

Comment: Maybe you could add the test as well, otherwise it's hard to tell why you believe the snapshot will be the same. Enzyme will always render `Title` and `Content` not sure how the snapshot could look like in your example.

Comment: @AndreasKöberle I have included my original test file and the snapshot it generates.

Comment: Strange for me it renders the expected snapshot: `<div><Content /><Title /></div>`. What version of  `enzyme ` and `enzyme-to-json` you use. Minor note I use `"snapshotSerializers": ["enzyme-to-json/serializer"]` in my jest settings, instead of `toJson(wrapper1)`. Not sure if this causes the problem.

Comment: @AndreasKöberle Hmm... so I have a configuration issue somewhere

Comment: @AndreasKöberle I have tried setting the snapshotSerializer, but still getting <Component/> in the snapshot, here are my package versions
 "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
 "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.1",
 "enzyme-to-json": "^3.3.3",

Comment: Looks like for some reason the components dont get the correct name, this normally happens when you use `export default () =>` instead of `export const ComponentName = () => `

Comment: Only differnence to my setup: `"enzyme-to-json": "3.3.1",`

Comment: @AndreasKöberle It appears downgrading to v3.3.1 for enzyme-to-json fixed the problem. I wonder if the change was intentional or by accident

Comment: Would make sense to open an issue for this

Comment: @AndreasKöberle Yup, doing it now. Thanks so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be some configuration issue. Instead of using toJson, I put the serializer in the jest config. And I downgraded the enzyme-to-json. And that solved the my problem. I then deleted my node_modules, and reinstalled everything.

Now that it's working, even if I change everything back to how it was to begin with, with enzyme-to-json at version 3.3.3, and using the toJson function, everything still works. I still don't know what the root cause was, but I'm suspecting something with how my packages were installed.